# How to get full participants in channel or group when using mtproto.call method?

Tags: bots, telegram

I have used @mtproto/core labary on nodejs. i did not how to get full participants in channel or group? I also change the limit or offset parameters but the result is only limited to 200 members.
my script:  Please help me!

```
try {
       const users= await mtproto.call('channels.getParticipants',
          {
           channel:inputChannel,
           filter: { _: 'channelParticipantsRecent' },
           offset:'',
           limit:1000
         });
         console.log(users)
    
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
     }
```